# How can I change the output value of an <option> if selected?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input

How can I give one element of a dropdown list a value and another element a different value?

I'm trying to output the different values into a input field when selected.
The following is just a visual, so you can understand the problem.

```
<label>Dropdown-List</label>
<select class="form-control" onchange="handicap();">
<option id="c1">Example (5)</option>
<option id="c2">Example (10)</option>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cap">

function handicap() {

  var cap1 = document.getElementById('c1');
  var cap2 = document.getElementById('c2');

  if (cap1) {
     document.getElementById('cap').value = 5;
  }

  else {
     document.getElementById('cap').value = 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get this _How can i give one element of a dropdown list a value, and another element a different value_ can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be `cap1.selected` instead of `cap1`. The condition you have at the moment becomes true in `if(cap1)` if `cap1` is not `null` or `undefined` thus, in each case `cap1` is defined so you were always getting that condition satisfied and the `input` was set with the value of `5` but now when you do `cap1.selected` it actually checks if the option `cap1` is selected or not.

```js
function handicap() {
  var cap1 = document.getElementById('c1');
  var cap2 = document.getElementById('c2');
  if (cap1.selected) {
     document.getElementById('cap').value = 5;
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById('cap').value = 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Dropdown-List</label>
<select class="form-control" onchange="handicap();">
<option id="c1">Example (5)</option>
<option id="c2">Example (10)</option>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cap">
```